# Automatically starting a program when another one starts

Tags: startup-applications, spotify

I want to make Spotify start Blockify, which is a program that automatically mutes your system when spotify is playing commercials, as soon as it start. 
How can I do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bash script (*filename.sh*) like this

```
#!/bin/bash

app1 &
app2 &
```

then change its permissions from a terminal

```
sudo chmod 0775 filename.sh
```

Now you can run your script like this

```
./filename.sh
```

Then, if you need it, you can even create a launcher targeting the script, which is going to start the two programs at the same time.

Comment: And then you can make an alias to run it even faster! `gedit ~/.bashrc`, then edit the very end of the file to include `alias aliasname='./filename.sh'`